# How to take sub-string or right for the following condition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

`Contract_Id` has data like

> abc_rev4,abc_rev1,xxxxx_rev2,yyyyyyyy_rev4 .

I would only need "rev" from the data.

Data always ends with single digit numeric.

So How would I extract rev with the help of `substring` or `right`

PS: Position of "v" in rev is always the last but first character

Comment: You should format the sample data and desired results as a table in the question.  You can put it in as text, then highlight it, and use <control>k for the formatting.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What is the output you desire? How many rows for each Contract_id - one for each "rev" in the input string? and what should be shown for each? Use your sample input to explain the desired output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will extract all instances of `rev` from the string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'abc_rev4,abc_rev1,xxxxx_rev2,yyyyyyyy_rev4',
         '[^,]+(rev)\d(,|$)',
         '\1\2'
       ) AS revs
FROM   DUAL
```

**Output**:

```
REVS
---------------
rev,rev,rev,rev
```

If you have each in a separate column then:

```
WITH table_name ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'abc_rev4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc_rev1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xxxxx_rev2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'yyyyyyyy_rev4' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR( value, -4, 3 ) AS rev
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE         REV
------------- ---
abc_rev4      rev
abc_rev1      rev
xxxxx_rev2    rev
yyyyyyyy_rev4 rev
```